# I am having diffculties with hiding the field in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have inherited a  purchase module, But I don't want the field "incoterm_id", I tried to hide it by using xpath and attribute, unfortunately its not hiding at all. this is my code.

```xml
<record id="view_construction_form" model= "ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.construction.form</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>

    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>

            <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[2]/group[1]/group[1]/field[@name='incoterm_id']"                 position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </xpath>   
     </form>
     </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following code:

```
<field name="incoterm_id" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</field>
```

Make sure you have listed view file in your *__ manifest __.py* file.

Afterwards restart your Odoo server and upgrade your module.

Comment: Thank you so much, Brother.